# Parse Structured Text File with into CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, export

I'm new to PowerShell and have searched and searched, but can't find the solution to what I'm trying to do.  I'd like to monitor a set of folders and if there is a change to any text file, then I'd like to insert that data into a csv file.  The text files will always be structured as the following, though the values (after a colon) may vary...

```
Type:   1 Red/1 Blue
SecondaryType:  
Keywords:   
Area:   150
Length: 28
Width:  22
System: 55.5cm
DateTime:   5/5/2017 10:06:38 PM
UserName:   bgates
Platform:   Major Platform 2017
CustomIdentifier:   1.11.0645.1330
Version:    14.116.65557.111
```

After the : there is a tab and then there may or may not be a value.

I've pieced together some code and it's exporting the csv, but not parsing correctly, I'm thinking because of the tab and often missing data.  Here's my code:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\03_InProgress"
$watcher.Filter = "*.txt"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  


$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            (Get-Content $path) -join "`r`n" -Split "(?m)^(?=\S)" |
                Where{$_} | 
                ForEach{
                    Clear-Variable PrimaryType,SecondaryType,Keywords,Area,Length,Width,System,DateTime,Username,Platform,CustomIdentifier,Version
                    Switch -regex ($_ -split "`r`n"){
                        "PrimaryType:" {$PrimaryType = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "SecondaryType:" {$SecondaryType = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Keywords:" {$Keywords = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Area:" {$Area = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Length:" {$Length = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Width:" {$Width = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "System:" {$System = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "DateTime:" {$DateTime = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Username:" {$Username = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Platform:" {$Platform = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "CustomIdentifier:" {$CustomIdentifier = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                        "Version:" {$Version = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
                    }
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        'PrimaryType' = $PrimaryType
                        'SecondaryType' = $SecondaryType
                        'Keywords' = $Keywords
                        'Area' = $Area
                        'Length' = $Length
                        'Width' = $Width
                        'System' = $System
                        'DateTime' = $DateTime
                        'Username' = $Username
                        'Platform' = $Platform
                        'CustomIdentifier' = $CustomIdentifier
                        'Version' = $Version }

                    $Files | ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{'PrimaryType' = $PrimaryType; 'SecondaryType' = $SecondaryType; 'Keywords' = $Keywords; 'Area' = $Area; 'Length' = $Length; 'Width' = $Width; 'System' = $System; 'DateTime' = $DateTime; 'Username' = $Username; 'Platform' = $Platform; 'CustomIdentifier' = $CustomIdentifier; 'Version' = $Version}}
                } | Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Smart Scrape\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
            ###Add-content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Smart Scrape\log.txt" -value $logline
          }    
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: What is `$Files` ? What is `Get-Content $path) -join "\`r\`n" -Split "(?m)^(?=\S)"` intended to do? And what "isn't parsing correctly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple parser for one of those files could be:

```
$Entries = [ordered]@{}

Get-Content $Path | ForEach-Object {

    $Key, $Value = $_ -split ':', 2
    $Entries[$Key.Trim()] = $Value.Trim()

}

[PSCustomObject]$Entries | Export-Csv -Append -Path "C:\Users\jrooker\Desktop\SmartPlan Scrape\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Which just splits each line by colon, only splitting into 2 to avoid breaking up the datetimes which have colons in them, then takes the left and the right and stores them in a hashtable (dictionary), and then converts that to a PSCustomObject for output.

It doesn't know what the field names are, and it doesn't look like it needs to.

Comment: Thank you!! Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
get-content $Path | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ":" -Header Name, Value | export-csv "C:\Users\jrooker\Desktop\SmartPlan Scrape\test.csv"  -notype -append
```

Short version with alias

```
gc $Path | ConvertFrom-Csv -D ":" -h Name, Value | epcsv "C:\Users\jrooker\Desktop\SmartPlan Scrape\test.csv" -not -a
```

Comment: Wow.  I was being somewhat masochistic, huh?  This works very well.  Thank you!